# Parsing unique string into a variable in the posix sh shell

Tags: shell, posix, sh

I have this weird behaviour that I can't understand; at some point I need to pass some flags to my script, one flag in particular is supposed to carry out a series of options used inside my script, for example I'm invoking my script as

```
sh script.sh --flag1="-options1=value1 -options2=value2" --flag2
```

the result is

```
-options1=value1
-options2=value2
1
```

,and so `flag1` magically appears as a multiline declaration and something happens and I don't really get the logic behind this behaviour.

This is the complete script

```
parse()
{
  while [ $# -gt 0 ]
  do
    case "$1" in
       --flag1=* ) FLAG_1="${1#*=}"; shift;;
       --flag2   ) FLAG_2="1"; shift;;
      (*) printf $0' : error - unrecognized option '$1'\n' 1>&2; exit 1;;
    esac
  done
}

printvar()
{
  printf %s'\n' $FLAG_1
  printf %s'\n' $FLAG_2
}


parse "$@"
printvar
```

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: You are printing `\n` (newline) after each flag.  Maybe remove that?

Comment: @JohnZwinck where ? I need `FLAG_1` as a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get FLAG_1 as a single line, just quote the variable:

```
printf "%s\n" "$FLAG_1"
```

The below snippet should clarify:

```
$ printf "%s\n" ab cd
ab
cd
$ printf "%s\n" "ab cd"
ab cd
```

Comment: I and why this is happening ? I checked and looks like the problem it's not even `printf`, it's how `FLAG_1` is storing the expansion.

Comment: No, the problem is specifically that you are not quoting the variable, so it gets expanded into multiple tokens by the shell.

Comment: @tripleee so the thing takes place outside my script ?

Comment: The unquoted variables are in the function `printvar`.  As far as I can understand your problem description, that is part of your script.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, the reason why it gets treated as several tokens is the expansion by the shell, but another possibly unexpected aspect is why this results in several lines printed which is an implementational detail of [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/printf.html): *"The format operand shall be reused as often as necessary to satisfy the argument operands."*. If it weren't for this, there wouldn't be multiple lines in OPs output word splitting by the shell/quoting or not.